# md5 sum in debian's official directory

Tags: debian, hashsum

Why there are 12 md5 sums while there are only 5 ISOs in Debian's official site?

http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-dvd/

I just download the `debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso` and check the md5 sum, which does not match the given value. Because the md5sum file in the above link has too many entries, therefore I doubt if it is my download error or their mistake, or I missed something..

Comment: Have you contacted the Debian CD team (details at the very same link that you provided)?  They'd be better placed to answer this sort of question.

Comment: @StephenHarris can't find their email

Comment: If click on the "Debian CD team" link on that page directly above the list of files you'll see all the details on how to contact them, including an email address.

Comment: @StephenHarris I'll send them an email.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Some Images are missing! Only the first n images are available! Where is the rest?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/index.en.html#not-all-images)

> We don't store/serve the full set of ISO images for all architectures, to reduce the amount of space taken up on the mirrors. You can use the [**jigdo**](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/index.en.html#why-jigdo) tool to recreate the missing ISO images instead.

Answer (score 4):

We don't publish all the images we make as ISO images, for the sake of our mirrors in both disk space and bandwidth. Use jigdo if you wish to create any of the other ISO images.

You can find a similar answer where I wrote it in the Debian CD FAQ too:

https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#not-all-images

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [list-dvd](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/list-dvd/), there are just as many lists as checksums in the files at the link you posted, ie. 13 and 2 for updates. Why are there only 3 iso's and 2 updates to download? That's another thing. But I can confirm the checksum for the first image is correct.

```
tomasz@E4200:~/Downloads$ md5sum debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso 
4892f11027491c16ed331bf13d78510b  debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso
```

Comment: Oh, my download has problem! `-> Downloads$ md5sum debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso 
bc24d88f26b180eb06e8c51e3d79d950  debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso
`

Comment: The size should be `3994091520`.

Comment: Oh, mine is : `-> Downloads$ ls debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso -al
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 3506092664 9月   1 21:11 debian-8.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso
`

Comment: Download again and it should be fine. You can make sure if you have enough space on the disk.

Comment: all right, this time I will download a live cd instead ;)